# ZK-GUI Test: How to query gui-element by UuiD?

Tags: java, testing, zk

so, i'm using **zats** for gui testing  and i would like to know if there is **any way to query the ui-elements by UuiD in ZATS** not by id that by dynamic elements doesn't exists. I've written IDGenerator for my dynamically generated gui elements (so now it sets UuiD all the elements). Now i need to query a certain element by UuiD. For example like this `desktopAgent.query"listbox[uuid='listbox_104']"` nothing happens.

So  this is method returns a list of components by UuiD

```
public List<ComponentAgent> queryAllByRegex(DesktopAgent desktop, String component) {
    List<ComponentAgent> componentList = new ArrayList<ComponentAgent>();
    // getting the last counter value for the desktop
    String MAX = (String) desktop.getAttribute(IDGenerator.LAST_COMPONENT_ID); // ?
    int max =Integer.parseInt(MAX);     
    // generate the pattern Exmpl: "listbox_[0-9]"
    String pattern = component + "_";
    String counter = "";
    for (int idx = 0; idx < MAX.length(); idx++) {
        counter = counter + "[0-9]";
    }
    pattern = pattern + counter;

    // genetrate regular expressions
    Generex generex = new Generex(pattern);

    // Using Generex iterator to iterate the recently generated list of strings by regex pattern
    Iterator iterator = generex.iterator();

    for(int i=0; i<=max;i++){
        //removes extra nulls
        String comp = removeNulls(iterator.next());
        ComponentAgent agent = desktop.query(component+"[uuid='"+comp+"']");
        if (agent != null) {
            componentList.add(agent);
            log.info("found by id" + comp);
        }
    }
    return componentList;

}
```

Here i get null what ever i tried

> ComponentAgent agent = desktop.query(component+"[uuid='"+comp+"']");

i'm really puzzled and i don't know if it at all possible to test my zk-gui with ZATS. THX

Answer (score 0):

You may create a method like this.

```
public ComponentAgent getComponentByUuid(DesktopAgent desktopAgent, String uuid) {
    return new DefaultComponentAgent(
            desktopAgent.getPages().get(0), desktopAgent.as(Desktop.class)
            .getComponentByUuidIfAny(uuid));
}
```